# Prevent top-level menu link in Wordpress admin menu from working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

**What am I trying to achieve.**

I have created a custom Top-level Wordpress menu and added a number of sub-menu items to it as well.

I don't actually need a page for the Top-level item - this is just something which I want to there as a 'heading' to hook the sub-menu items to.

Ideally i'd like it so when you move your cursor onto the top-level item, the sub-menu flies out (which it does by default) but if you click on it nothing happens.

**A working solution**

This jQuery now works - just make sure you clear your browser cache properly if you are struggling.

```
// Javascript

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('a.toplevel_page_menu_slug').click(function(event) { // where 'menu_slug' is your menu slug
    /*alert ('working'); - Testing purposes only */
    event.preventDefault(); // cancel the event
});
});
```

And this CSS changes the cursor on mouse over to be the default, not the pointer.

```
//CSS 
a.toplevel_page_menu_slug {
cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: elaborate on 'isn't working' is the alert even firing?

Comment: Nothing happens - not even the alert. Updated to reflect this.

Comment: Is this on the admin section of Wordpress or the actual website ? Is the menu generated through the "menu" widget in Wordpress?

Comment: check if your links have that click event attatched. For example Firefox shows a little `ev` icon after Elements that have events attatched.

Comment: show us relevant generated html, maybe your selector is wrong, and preventDefault doesnt cancel alert(working)

Comment: OK - I think I was struggling with browser caching. Sorted now and I've added some helpful CSS to finish off the solution. Thx All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously your script is either not loaded or the selector is not working. This is how you should include your script in WP Admin:

```
function preventTopLevelLink() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'prevent_top_level_link', get_template_directory_uri() . '/myscript.js' );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'preventTopLevelLink' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts

Your script should basically work, try it like this:

```
(function($) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).on('click','a.toplevel_page_menu_slug',function(event) { // where 'menu_slug' is your menu slug
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault(); // cancel the event
     });
   });
})(jQuery);
```